# JavaFX - Simple flip card (change two image with delay 2 sec)

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I'm creating a simple memory game with cards image: user tries to find two card with the same image. For start I create a button with image of closed card. When user clicks on button, program changes image of picture on picture of open card, wait 2 seconds and changes picture back. And I stucked on it.

When user click on button, I run three another threads in action listener of the button: fist changes closed picture on open picture, second waits 2 seconds, third changes picture back. But instead of it, the changes in the ui occur only when all threads exit

Code of action list

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Runnable r1 = ()->{
            synchronized (btn) {
                System.out.println("test");
                Image image2 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("img/open.jpg"));
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(image2);
                iv.setFitWidth(100);
                iv.setFitHeight(100);
                Platform.runLater(()->btn.setGraphic(iv));
            }

        };

        Runnable r2 = ()->{

            synchronized (btn) {
                System.out.println("test2");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("test2 end");
            }
        };
        Runnable r3=()->{
            synchronized (btn) {
                System.out.println("test3");
                Image image2 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("img/unnamed.jpg"));
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(image2);
                iv.setFitWidth(100);
                iv.setFitHeight(100);
                btn.setGraphic(iv);
            }
        };

        Platform.runLater(r1);
        Platform.runLater(r2);
        Platform.runLater(r3);

    }
});
```

Comment: Your code pauses JavaFX's GUI thread for 2 seconds at `r2`. A much more reliable solution is to use JavaFX's [`Timeline`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) feature. For example a simple countdown using a `TimeLine` you can find here: https://asgteach.com/2011/10/javafx-animation-and-binding-simple-countdown-timer-2/

Comment: *"When user click on button, I run three another threads"* no you don't. You just schedule 3 runnables to be executed on the javafx application thread at a later time. `r2` is still a long-running task, so the only difference compared to running all the code from the runnables directly the fact that there's it happens a bit later. Neither the synchronisation nor the `Platform.runLater` calls inside the runnables provied any benefit, since the runnables are executed in sequence on the javafx application thread.

Comment: If you really want to use threads you need to do so the same way you'd create a thread in any other java application, e.g. by doing `new Thread(runnable).start()`; there doesn't seem to be any good reason to use 3 seperate threads though. this just adds unnecessary complexity for logic that's supposed to be executed in order. If you did indeed start threads instead of using `Platform.runLater` at the end of your code, you'd have absolutely no control over which runnable enters it's critical section first resulting in a non-deterministic update sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you're not actually creating any threads at all here; all you're doing is scheduling three chunks of code to run on the FX Application Thread (the thread you're currently on) at some point in the future, one after the other. One of those chunks of code pauses the FX Application Thread for two seconds, which will prevent it from doing what it's supposed to be doing (rendering the UI and handling user events) during that time. Hence you don't actually see the results of the code in `r1`, because the UI isn't rendered during the pause created by `r2`, and then `r3` is immediately executed.

All you need here is to execute the code in `r1`, and then to execute the code in `r3` after two seconds. The easiest way to accomplish this is with a [`PauseTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html):

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Image image2 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("img/open.jpg"));
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(image2);
        iv.setFitWidth(100);
        iv.setFitHeight(100);
        btn.setGraphic(iv);

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
            Image image2 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("img/unnamed.jpg"));
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(image2);
            iv.setFitWidth(100);
            iv.setFitHeight(100);
            btn.setGraphic(iv);
        });
        pause.play();
    }
});
```

There's also no real reason to create two `ImageView`s; you can just update the image, and no need to reload the images every time the button is pressed (you can use the same image in multiple image views, if you need). And if you use lambda expressions for your event handler, your code simplifies to

```
// you can scope these as widely as you need: you should only load them once
Image openImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("img/open.jpg"));
Image unnamedImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("img/unnamed.jpg"));

// this needs to be specific to this button:
ImageView iv = new ImageView();
iv.setFitWidth(100);
iv.setFitHeight(100);

btn.setOnAction(event -> {
    iv.setImage(openImage);
    btn.setGraphic(iv);

    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
    pause.setOnFinished(e -> iv.setImage(unnamedImage));
    pause.play();

});
```